# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I'm getting this strange error after deploy a web app to the remote host.

`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<error> has no method 'endsWith'`

Facts:

- The app works perfectly fine on my local machine as a host.
- The app throws this error when deployed to IIS in a remote host.
- The files loaded by the app are the same in both scenarios.

The files loaded are these:

[image]

The files are being written as follows:

[image]

The methods are these:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function (toMatch) {
    var self = this;
    return self.indexOf(toMatch) == 0;
};

String.prototype.endsWith = function (toMatch) {
    var self = this;
    return self.toLowerCase().indexOf(toMatch.toLowerCase(), 
        self.length - toMatch.length) !== -1;
};

String.prototype.contains = function (toMatch) {
    var self = this;
    return self.indexOf(toMatch) !== -1;
};
```

I'm no master with javascript but when I access the prototype object the intellisense shows me this:

[image]

Comment: Show us the line of code that throws the exception. Is that `Object #<error>` really a string? Did you load the prototype methods before you did use them (and do you guarantee that order, load times might change when deploying)?

Comment: I created this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/UjTzH/1/) and it worked fine?

Comment: @Bergi: now that you mention the ordering, no. they're at the very botton of the file, but why do this works local and not at the remote server? I will extend the question with further info on the error.

Comment: @rontornambe: the jsfiddle works fine!

Comment: I guess the salient question is "why is the function not being resolved on the server?". Are you certain all the files on the remote system are in the same folders as they are locally?

Comment: If they are included with static (not dynamically created) `<script>` tags (without `async` attributes) they will be loaded in the declared order.

Comment: @Bergi: now I feel terrible that `Object #<error>` wasn't a string. Now I fixed it. Thank you! Pleas post your answer here and I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible reasons for this exception:

- The prototype-extending script was not yet loaded (which especially might change on deployment, when loaded asynchronically without caution), did not get executed correctly or the methods got `delete`d thereafter (unlikely)
- or that mysterious `Object #<error>` is not `String` instance. Looks like if that was the problem :-)

Comment: +1 Thank you very much for your comment, I wasn't able to detect what the error was, you gave me a hell of a pointer!